# Confused, new action not rendered after validation failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So i have the following code:

```
def new 
    @all_areas = Area.all
    @area = Area.new
end
```

The reason i am passing in all_areas is it's required for a drop down box in the form, Using mongoid and an Area can be recursively embedded in another Area.

My form has the following code:

```
 <% if @all_areas %>
        <%= f.label :parent_area %>
        <%= f.collection_select(:parent_area, @all_areas, :_id, :name, prompt: "Select a Parent...") %>
    <% end %>
```

However when i submit 'invalid values, i.e blank name, the 'new' page does not render the select box to select a parent.

What is going on here? Is this a bug?

My create action is pretty simple, if it fails validation i just do the following:

```
else
     render 'new'
```

Why is @all_areas not passed to the view the second time? i have actually fixed it by changing the code in my create action to the following:

```
else
    @all_areas = Area.all
    render 'new'
```

But this is quite surprising, unless i am missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a bug. The reason for the behaviour is that the `create` action is actually quite separate from the `new` action, so the instance variables you assigned in `new` don't get carried over. `render 'new'` only renders the view called "new", it doesn't actually call the `new` action.

`new` happens when you issue a `GET` request to `/areas/new`. `create` happens when you `POST` to `/areas`. Because they're separate requests, the server doesn't remember any state - in fact, you could call `create` without ever calling `new` (say if you used curl from the command line).

Basically, your approach is correct, you need to set the `@all_areas` instance variable in *both* actions. You might want to extract it out into a separate private method to avoid the duplication.